# How to do an SQL query in C++ to define a variable

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've been searching all day to figure out how to do an SQL query in c++ and then store the result as a variable.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, connected to the SQL database, and ran the following query successfully inside Visual Studio:

```
SELECT Beta FROM Equity WHERE Ticker = 'AAPL'
```

I want to be able to run that query in my c++ program and then store the result in a variable so that it can be used in a calculation. How can this be done?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get an [SQL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205802/best-portable-way-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-c), depending on that you will need to write some set-up code and execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

BY C++ I'm sure you mean a native C++ application, not a managed  C++ one. You need to use one of libraries that connect to SQL Server. Choices are:

- [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see [ODBC database sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ODBC-sample-191624ae)
- [OLE DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see [Sample OLE DB Consumer Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a programability extension on top of OLE DB. See [ADO Code Examples in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My recommendation would be to use ODBC. You have a quite a lot to read and learn before you can actually get an example running with the query you asked. Good luck.